# R, ggpubr: Disable exponents on logaritmic scale axis and use integer numbers instead

Tags: r, logarithm, ggpubr

I am trying to plot my data using logarithmic scales on y and x axis. But, I would like to  disable exponent notation on logarithmic scale on my plot. Instead of 10^0,10^1,10^2, I would  like to have 1, 10, 100...

Please, how can I accomplish this within `ggpubr` package?

[image]

Dummy data:

```
require(ggpubr)

data(cars)
p <- ggscatter(cars, x = "speed", y = "dist")

p + yscale("log10", .format = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `format` to `FALSE` (the default value) gives that:

```
p + yscale("log10")
```

[image]